# Are there any scriptures which talk about Mantra Diskha?

Tags: mantras, initiation, japa

I have heard that only few people are able to initiate someone with a mantra diksha where a student is given a particular mantra with some “secret syllables” in it.

My questions is
- how is it different from doing japa with a regular mantra

Comment: For that you should clarify what do you mean by regular mantra? There are many agama texts which deals with diksha adhikara and paddhati

Comment: I am more inclined towards Advaita. So let’s say if do Jappa with a mantra like “hari om tat sat” or others....why is that different from lets say a mantra prescribed via diksha?

Comment: because Vedanta dont have concept of mantra marga. In fact they also renounce all the vedic rites and rituals. So its more of renouncing and giving up things rather than taking up. They usually do not follow mantra or upasana marga. These are more predominant in agamic traditions.

Comment: There are plenty of scriptures that talk about Mantra Diksha primarily Tantras, Puranas. The Vedic Diksha is called Upanayana where the Mantra being given to the disciple is the Gayatri Mantra. @PJai

Comment: Guru Geeta discusses it. Guru gives a mantra powered with his Tapobal so that fruit comes faster, but regular mantra also works in Kalayug. Problem is there are so many Mantras and prayers. Gayatri Mantra is highest among regular mantras